# Create a dictionary from list of tuples based on first element

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples that look like this:

```
[('name', 'Name'),('name','Age'),('name','Hometown'),('value','Bob'),('value',27),('value','Chicago'),('name','Home Team'),('name','Away Team'),('name','Score'),('value','Broncos'),('value','Patriots'),('name','Month'),('value','January'),...]
```

Essentially what this is is a bunch of tables. For example, the first table would have the headers 'Name', 'Age', and 'Hometown' and the entry would be 'Bob', 27, 'Chicago'.

I am trying to turn this into one dictionary like this: `{'Name':'Bob','Age':27,'Hometown':'Chicago, 'Home Team':'Broncos',...}`

I believe I can do this in a normal case, however if you look at the second "table" there are 3 headers and only 2 values. Is there a way to map the first two 'names' in that case to the first two 'values' and map the third (`'Score'`) to an empty string?

Comment: In the case where there is a missing value, how would you know which of the named values should be blank?  If there are 3 "named" items in table and only 2 values, how would you determine if the blank is in the 1st, 2nd or 3rd position?

Comment: @JeffH For now I just want to assume the last name is the one that is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works.  May not be real pretty, but it should be rugged if you have several segments with missing values, and does not require altering the original list...  Although I just learned `zip_longest`.  Thanks @Zunayn

A little while loop construct can chew through this:

```
data = [('name', 'Name'),('name','Age'),('name','Hometown'),('value','Bob'),('value',27),('value','Chicago'),
('name','Home Team'),('name','Away Team'),('name','Score'),('value','Broncos'),('value','Patriots'),('name','Month'),('value','January')]

# reverse the data for more efficient pop()
data = data[::-1]

results = {}
d = data.pop()
while data:
    keys = []
    while d[0] == 'name':
        keys.append(d[1])
        d = data.pop()
    values = []
    while d[0] == 'value':
        values.append(d[1])
        if data:   # need to watch for end of list
            d = data.pop()
        else:
            break
    missing = len(keys) - len(values)
    values.extend(['na']*missing)

    # zip intermediate results and add to result
    results.update({k:v for (k, v) in zip(keys, values)})

print(results)
```

Yields:

```
{'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 27, 'Hometown': 'Chicago', 'Home Team': 'Broncos', 'Away Team': 'Patriots', 'Score': 'na', 'Month': 'January'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ol = [('name', 'Name'),
      ('name','Age'),
      ('name','Hometown'),
      ('value','Bob'),
      ('value',27),
      ('value','Chicago'),
      ('name','Home Team'),
      ('name','Away Team'),
      ('name','Score'),
      ('value','Broncos'),
      ('value','Patriots'),
      ('name','Month'),
      ('value','January')]
l = ol.copy()
d = {}
noValue = False
while len(l) > 0 :
    i = 1
    while l[i][0] != 'value':
        i += 1
    d[l[0][1]] = l[i][1]
    if i == 2 and l[i+1][0] == 'name':
        d[l[1][1]] = ''
        l = l[i + 1:]
    else:
        l = l[1:i] + l[i + 1:]

print(d)
```

Printing:

```
{'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 27, 'Hometown': 'Chicago', 'Home Team': 'Broncos', 'Away Team': 'Patriots', 'Score': '', 'Month': 'January'}
```

This should work as long as only the last value is missing.
This list will not work `[('name','Home Team'), ('name','Away Team'), ('name','Score'), ('value','Broncos'), ('name','Month'), ('value','January')]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I propose:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

tup = [('name', 'Name'),('name','Age'),('name','Hometown'),('value','Bob'),('value',27),('value','Chicago'),('name','Home Team'),('name','Away Team'),('value','Broncos'),('value','Patriots'),('name','Month'),('value','January'), ('name','Score')]

 names = [item[1] for item in tup if item[0] == "name"]
 values = [item[1] for item in tup if item[0] == "value"]
 d = dict(zip_longest(names, values, fill_value=""))
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 27, 'Hometown': 'Chicago', 'Home Team': 'Broncos', 'Away Team': 'Patriots', 'Month': 'January', 'Score': ''}
```

You could use the standard `zip()` function but as you said, you need to map the surplus keys to an empty string. For that purpose, use `itertools.zip_longest`. And, remember that order is everything while zipping two iterables. In your question, the tuple `("name", "Score")` comes before `("name", "Month")`, and the last "value" is `("value", "January")`. This would map "Score" to January and not "Month". So, I changed the order in my example.

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I just suggest, maybe do something like this. Of cource it will work if you names and values are stored in order.

1. Start with pulling tuples with key 'name' from list and stop if occur 'value' tuple.
2. Create dictionary from that keys, where every value is empty string temporarily.
3. Go back to list and pull values and set in order into dict.
4. If another 'name' tuple occurs, then go back to point 1. If there is no value for some key in previous dict, then it will be empty string.